# How to implement actions for CheckBoxPreference button?

Tags: android, mobile-development

I can't find a proper way to implement functionality of shared preference, to be clear I have added a "CheckBoxPreference" that will enable full screen mode/immersive mode, I know how to do it directly, but I don't know how to control its functionality.

Here, I have made a separate class for shared preference:

SharedPreferenceActivity.java

```
package com.nurujjamanpollob.website; 

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.preference.*; 
import android.content.*; 
import android.view.*; 
import android.os.*; 
import android.app.*; 
import java.util.prefs.*; 
import android.widget.*; 
import android.util.*;

public class PreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    SharedPreferences Preferences; 
    CheckBoxPreference checkbox; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); //set the default values we defined in the XML
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
}
```

And here is my, "res/xml/preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <PreferenceCatagory android:title="General Option <CheckBoxPreference android:key="immersive_mode" android:title="Full Screen Mode" android:summary="Enable Full Screen Mode" </PreferenceCatagory> </PreferenceScreen>
```

Or may I need to add something to main activity!

How to implement its action when I checked and unchecked?

Use a toast for introduce me Where to add my self code logic.

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: This is a poorly asked question. How about reformatting the code ?

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code; you should do that yourself next time. An unreadable question is unlikely to get answers. Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for editing sir.but help me please!

Comment: I have understood that situation and added more details.